# Что значит ошибка "Непредвиденное появление: (." в BAT файле?

Tags: bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET current_dir=%cd%
SET execute_filename=run.py

IF EXIST env\ (
  CALL %current_dir%\env\Scripts\activate.bat
  python %execute_filename%
) ELSE (
    ECHO Enviroment not found, try to create and install requirements?
    SET /p inp="Press Y to continue or any other key to exit:"
    
    IF NOT %inp%==Y (
      ECHO Exiting...
      EXIT
    )

    ECHO First updating pip, setuptools, wheel to latest version...
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
    ECHO Installing requirements...
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
    ECHO Installing requirements done.
    python %execute_filename%
)
pause
```

Есть такой скрипт простенький, но он ругается на код с содержимым:

```
IF NOT %inp%==Y (
   ECHO Exiting...
   EXIT
)
```

Сама ошибка: `Непредвиденное появление: (.`

Обе скобки в порядке и открываются и закрываются, в чём может проблема и что ему не нравиться?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `IF NOT %inp%==Y` использовать `IF %inp% NEQ Y`.

Answer (score 0):

Переходы из скобок наружу, мне кажется.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]